# How to restart function within the function?

Tags: php, function, variables

I have a function setup to a button, and when the if condition is false, it works, but when it is true it just keeps on loading, so i assume my trying to call the function to start again isnt working, is there any better way to do this?

All i want to do is, if, 'if' is true then it restarts the function.

Example - This doesnt run.

```
function modulename_mycode($params) {

XXX

XXX

XXX

XXX 

YYY

YYY

YYY
$data = 'XXX';
$word = 'YYY';
if(strpos($data, $word) !==false){
  modulename_mycode();
}
```

Comment: Where is `mycode();` defined? I only see `modulename_mycode()`.

Comment: Your function name is `modulename_mycode` and you are calling `mycode` ?

Comment: And what is all the `XXX` and `YYY`?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton sorry i made a typo here, i am calling modulename_mycode(); only but it doesn't execute :(

Comment: @HarishST sorry i made a typo here, i am calling modulename_mycode(); only but it doesn't execute :(

Comment: @AbraCadaver thats the part of the code.

Comment: @Harsh Part of the Code? Then you should be getting Error.

Comment: @Harsh That tells me this isn't your actual code, why not just provide your actual code?

Comment: @HarishST i have redacted the code

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, because it is way too long, and with a lot of variables. I just want to be able to rerun the code when it hits the if condition, and go with different variable from above code

Comment: @Harsh Well, there is no way for us to tell you why your code isn't working when we can't see the code. I don't feel like you are gonna get much help. If you made a typo that big, how do you know you didn't make another typo which actually would have fixed your problem in your code?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, because half of my code works i.e when output of if is false, it works, but when output is true, it just keeps on loading, plus there is no error in error_log or debug mode.

Comment: @Harsh Okay, well, suit yourself. I'm going to move on to other questions because I'm not able to help you with your question in it's current state and you won't help me help you.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton there - https://3v4l.org/Uuc0U

Comment: @Harsh Could you try changing the line which you use to call the function again with this? `return virtualizor_testing($params);`

Comment: @grumpyCrouton negative, still same, keeps on loading.

Comment: @Harsh That may mean it's an endless loop? I mean, every time you run the function, the results would be the same right? You don't change anything inside that IF statement.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, correct it will remain same, no change, only variables would be changed inside.

Comment: @GrumpCrouton, i have updated the code  little - https://3v4l.org/hSuXo

Now finally can see error, still don't know how to sort this `'PHP message: [Application] ERROR: Error: Call to undefined function get_data() `

The problem is at print `print_r(get_data($url));`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, thanks for your help, i have changed the whole code and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this with the help of @GrumpyCrouton.

The right way to do it was

```
return modulename_mycode($params);
```

substitute your modulename and it should call the function you want, this is good for WHMCS modules too.